# Is $\omega = dU = sin(x+y)dx+cos(x+y)dy$ an exact form?

Tags: analysis, integration, differential-forms

In my thermodynamics homework I should prove that $dU = sin(x+y)dx+cos(x+y)dy$ is a function of state. Which means it's integration over any path be constant or in other word $dU$ should be an exact form.
I used the *Poincare Lemma* and had the following calculus:
$$d\omega =(D_1sin(x+y)dx+D_2sin(x+y)dy)\wedge dx+(D_1cos(x+y)dx+D_2cos(x+y)dy)\wedge dy$$
$$= -(cos(x+y)+sin(x+y))dx\wedge dy$$
which is not zero. So $\omega$ isn't a closed so an exact so a function of state.
Can you help me please?

Comment: $\omega = dU$ That is since $\omega$ is differential of $U$ so it is exact. But $d [\sin\ (x+y) dx +\cos\ (x+y) dy] = [-\cos\ (x+y) -\sin\ (x+y)]dx\wedge dy \neq 0$ So in fact it is not closed so that it is not exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\large\mbox{It's not !!!}$

$$
{\partial U \over \partial x} =  \sin\left(x + y\right)\,,
\quad
U = -\cos\left(x + y\right) + \phi\left(y\right)
$$

$$
{\partial U \over \partial y} =  \sin\left(x + y\right) + \phi'\left(y\right)
\color{#ff0000}{\LARGE\not=}
\cos\left(x + y\right)
$$